# How to control Material-ui <Autocompelete /> by option id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When working with HTML select in React, we tend to use an id or key to track the value selected:

```
<select value={value} onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}>
  {options.map((option) => (
    <option value={option.id}>{option.label}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

I wonder if we can do the same with Material-ui Autocompelete component since in its [demo](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground), the value set in state is the whole object instead of the object id.

I tried using its APIs in the following way which make sense to me but it doesn't work as expected:

```
const fruits = [
  { id: 0, label: "apple" },
  { id: 1, label: "banana" },
  { id: 2, label: "cherries" },
  { id: 3, label: "fig" }
];

function FruitPicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="fruit-picker"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, option) => {
        setValue(option?.id || null);
      }}
      options={fruits}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      getOptionSelected={(option) => option.id === value}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Fruit" />}
      openOnFocus
    />
  );
}
```

I had created this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flight-hardiness-tripping-decipher-76vpj?file=/demo.js) if you want to play around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I used.

```
<Autocomplete
 options={fruits}
 value={fruits.filter(el => el.id === currentValue)[0]}
 getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
 onChange={(event, option) => { setValue(option?.id || null); }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you pass the `options` of array object, so when set value `onChange`, you must still keep `setValue(option)`, but on `getOptionSelected`, compare their ids instead

```
<Autocomplete
  value={value}
  onChange={(event, option) => {
    setValue(option);
  }}
  options={fruits}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
  getOptionSelected={(option) => option.id === value.id}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Fruit" />}
  openOnFocus
/>
```